# DataTable sorting: make one column stay fixed

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin. Sorting works fine, but is there a way to make one column stay always the same no matter what sorting is applied?

For example, the first column are just simple order numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
And when I sort by date, or anything else, the first column stays in the same order: 1, 2, 3..?

Is there a way to do this? So, I am not trying to disable sorting by first column, but make the first column stay the same when sorting is applied by another columns.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this question while looking for solution for the same problem.
Here is a solution as contained in the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0
    } ],
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );

t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

} );

Basically the index column is re-numbered whenever an `order` or `search` event is fired. `searchable` and `orderable` are set to false since they have no effect on the index column (It will still be re-numbered anyways).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [orderFixed](http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed) option which defines ordering that will be always applied to the table.

For example, to always sort the first column in ascending order:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "orderFixed": [ 0, 'asc' ]
} );
```

Comment: Thank you just what I wanted

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML code will look something like this. Add a class to the columns you want to disable sorting on.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="example" >
<thead>
<tr id="tbl_header1">
    <th  class="no-sort" name="prop_ref_no" style="min-width:80px">PropRef</th>
    <th  class="no-sort" name="title" style="min-width:80px">title</th>
    <th  name="publish_status" style="min-width:80px">Publish status</th>
    <th  name="Bedrooms" style="min-width:200px">Bedrooms</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Then add this your dataTable options.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": 'no-sort',
      "orderable": false,
} ]} );
```

SRC: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21164/disable-sorting-of-one-column

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that's exactly what I am NOT trying to do, I assumed that everyone is going to suggest that, so I was explicit in my message:

"So, I am not trying to disable sorting by first column, but make the first column stay the same when sorting is applied by another columns."